# Fail to generate code for a wsdl with axis 1.4, although when imported at SoapUI is consumed successfully

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui, axis, wsimport

I have a wsdl, which when I import it at SoapUI (5.5.0) it runs as expected - I can make ws requests - I get ws responses. The ws is protected with using username/password. We are ok.

======= Error on code generation

But when trying to generate code using Axis 1.4 lib with SoapUI, it fails with following error:

```
Running Axis 1.x wsdl2java for [xgen_poke]
directory: C:\dev\libs\axis-1_4\lib
command: [java, -cp, axis-ant.jar;axis.jar;commons-discovery-0.2.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;jaxrpc.jar;log4j-1.2.8.jar;saaj.jar;wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar, org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java, -v, -T, 1.1, -o, C:\dev\projects, -U, wsuser, -P, ws2021*, http://example:8080/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/srvc_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke?sap-client=200?wsdl]
- Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Parsing XML file:  http://example:8080/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/srvc_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke?sap-client=200?wsdl
WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsp:Policy): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Encountered unexpected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy}Policy'.: 
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOMUtils.throwWSDLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parsePortType(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:516)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

======= Check WSI compliance report

```
The conformance validation process failed.
Exception:org.wsi.WSIException
WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsp:Policy): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Encountered unexpected '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy}Policy'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nested exception is: 
WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsp:Policy): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: 
Encountered unexpected '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy}Policy'.: 
at org.wsi.test.profile.validator.impl.wsdl.WSDLValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at org.wsi.test.analyzer.BasicProfileAnalyzer.validateWSDL(Unknown Source)
at org.wsi.test.analyzer.BasicProfileAnalyzer.validateConformance(Unknown Source)
at org.wsi.test.analyzer.BasicProfileAnalyzer.main(Unknown Source)
```

The used wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
   <wsdl:documentation>
      <sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl"/>
   </wsdl:documentation>
   <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN__xgen_poke">
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>
         <wsp:All>
            <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"/>
            <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>
            <saptrnbnd:OptimizedMimeSerialization wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
            <wsp:All>
               <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:HttpsToken>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                 <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                           </sp:HttpsToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:TransportToken>
                     <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                     <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:Layout>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:TransportBinding>
            </wsp:All>
         </wsp:All>
         <wsp:All>
            <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"/>
            <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>
            <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/"/>
            <wsp:All>
               <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:HttpsToken>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                 <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                           </sp:HttpsToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:TransportToken>
                     <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                     <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:Layout>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:TransportBinding>
            </wsp:All>
         </wsp:All>
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>
   </wsp:Policy>
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN__xgen_poke_soap12">
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>
         <wsp:All>
            <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"/>
            <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>
            <saptrnbnd:OptimizedMimeSerialization wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
            <wsp:All>
               <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:HttpsToken>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                 <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                           </sp:HttpsToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:TransportToken>
                     <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                     <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:Layout>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:TransportBinding>
            </wsp:All>
         </wsp:All>
         <wsp:All>
            <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"/>
            <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>
            <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/"/>
            <wsp:All>
               <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:HttpsToken>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                 <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                           </sp:HttpsToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:TransportToken>
                     <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                     <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:Layout>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:TransportBinding>
            </wsp:All>
         </wsp:All>
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>
   </wsp:Policy>
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF__XGEN_POKE">
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>
         <wsp:All>
            <sapsession:Session xmlns:sapsession="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
               <sapsession:enableSession>false</sapsession:enableSession>
            </sapsession:Session>
            <sapcentraladmin:CentralAdministration wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:sapcentraladmin="http://www.sap.com/webas/700/soap/features/CentralAdministration/">
               <sapcentraladmin:BusinessApplicationID>00155DDDBA1B1EE680FA460890A4F195</sapcentraladmin:BusinessApplicationID>
            </sapcentraladmin:CentralAdministration>
         </wsp:All>
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>
   </wsp:Policy>
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP__XgenPoke">
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>
         <wsp:All>
            <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>
            <sapcomhnd:enableCommit xmlns:sapcomhnd="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/commit/">false</sapcomhnd:enableCommit>
            <sapblock:enableBlocking xmlns:sapblock="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/blocking/">true</sapblock:enableBlocking>
            <saprmnw05:enableWSRM xmlns:saprmnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/wsrm/">false</saprmnw05:enableWSRM>
         </wsp:All>
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>
   </wsp:Policy>
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
         <xsd:simpleType name="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
         </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:schema>
      <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
         <xsd:import namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"/>
         <xsd:element name="XgenPoke">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="Claimid" type="n0:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="Notificationtype" type="n0:string"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
         <xsd:element name="XgenPokeResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="EClaimid" type="n0:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="EError" type="n0:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="EIsreceivedok" type="n0:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="ENotificationtype" type="n0:string"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="XgenPoke">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:XgenPoke"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="XgenPokeResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:XgenPokeResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="XGEN_POKE">
      <wsdl:documentation>
         <sapdoc:sapdoc xmlns:sapdoc="urn:sap:esi:documentation">
            <sapdoc:docitem docURL="http://example.com:8080/sap/bc/esdt/docu/sd_text?sap-client=200&amp;sd_name=XGEN_POKE"/>
         </sapdoc:sapdoc>
      </wsdl:documentation>
      <wsp:Policy>
         <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#IF__XGEN_POKE"/>
      </wsp:Policy>
      <wsdl:operation name="XgenPoke">
         <wsp:Policy>
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP__XgenPoke"/>
         </wsp:Policy>
         <wsdl:input message="tns:XgenPoke"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:XgenPokeResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="xgen_poke" type="tns:XGEN_POKE">
      <wsp:Policy>
         <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN__xgen_poke"/>
      </wsp:Policy>
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="XgenPoke">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style:XGEN_POKE:XgenPokeRequest" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:binding name="xgen_poke_soap12" type="tns:XGEN_POKE">
      <wsp:Policy>
         <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN__xgen_poke_soap12"/>
      </wsp:Policy>
      <wsoap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="XgenPoke">
         <wsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style:XGEN_POKE:XgenPokeRequest" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <wsoap12:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <wsoap12:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="xgen_poke">
      <wsdl:port name="xgen_poke" binding="tns:xgen_poke">
         <soap:address location="http://example.com:8080/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="xgen_poke_soap12" binding="tns:xgen_poke_soap12">
         <wsoap12:address location="http://example.com:8080/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

======= try to generate wsdl also with with installed-jdk-7/bin/wsimport.exe

```
wsimport.exe -keep -verbose http://password@example:8080/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/srvc_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke?sap-client=200?wsdl
```

And got again error:

```
[failed to localize] wsimport.ParsingWSDL()
[failed to localize] wsimport.ErrorMessage([failed to localize] wsimport.authInfoNeeded(
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: username:password@example:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/srvc_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke?sap-client=200?wsdl, 
username:password@example:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/srvc_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/xgen_poke/200/xgen_poke/xgen_poke?sap-client=200?wsdl, 
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.metro\auth))
```

> Info: I have replaced part of url/username/password with dummy data for
> privacy reasons

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

```
WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsp:Policy): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Encountered unexpected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy}Policy'.
```